# PHP/MySQL: Insert Into Table 1 values from a Foreign Key's Table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on a Tabletop RPG Monster Database for a class, and I need to insert values into my Monster Table with these parameters: [Monster Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZNon.png).

```
CREATE TABLE Monsters (
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
HP int unsigned NOT NULL,
MP int unsigned NOT NULL,
AC int unsigned NOT NULL,
MonsterType_ID int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ID),
FOREIGN KEY(MonsterType_ID) REFERENCES MonsterType(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I also have a [MonsterType Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtDqu.png)

```
CREATE TABLE MonsterType (  
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
Name varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (ID)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I have PHP code set up: [PHP Monster Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1RwQ.png)

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if( (isset($_POST["Name"]) && $_POST["Name"] !== "") && 
    (isset($_POST["HP"]) && $_POST["HP"] !== "") &&
    (isset($_POST["MP"]) && $_POST["MP"] !== "") &&
    (isset($_POST["AC"]) && $_POST["AC"] !== "") &&
    (isset($_POST["MonsterType_ID"]) && $_POST["MonsterType_ID"] !== "") ) {



            $query = "INSERT INTO Monsters ";
            $query .= "(Name, HP, MP, AC, MonsterType_ID) ";
            $query .= "VALUES (";
            $query .= "'".$_POST["Name"]."',";
            $query .= "'".$_POST["HP"]."',";
            $query .= "'".$_POST["MP"]."',";
            $query .= "'".$_POST["AC"]."',";
            $query .= "'".$_POST["MonsterType_ID"]."');";

            $result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

When I go to [Add Monsters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvloU.png), the Monster Type field only accepts integer values corresponding to the MonsterType.ID index. Instead, I'd like to be able to, in the text field, type out the [MonsterType Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIqgX.png)

```
INSERT INTO MonsterType (Name)
VALUES
    ('Abberation'),
    ('Beast'),
    ('Celestial'),
    ('Construct'),
    ('Dragon'),
    ('Elemental'),
    ('Fey'),
    ('Fiend'),
    ('Giant'),
    ('Humanoid'),
    ('Monstrosity'),
    ('Ooze'),
    ('Plant'),
    ('Undead');
```

and have the corresponding Type Name's ID inserted into the database.

I can already [display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO88Q.png) the MonsterType associated with the Monster using this query: [Monster Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDG5Z.png)

```
$query = "SELECT Monsters.ID AS `mID`, 
          Monsters.Name AS `MName`, Monsters.MonsterType_ID, 
          MonsterType.Name FROM Monsters ";
$query .= "inner join MonsterType ON Monsters.MonsterType_ID = MonsterType.ID 
          ORDER BY MonsterType.Name ASC";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if ($result && $result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    echo "<center>";
    echo "<h2>The Monster Database</h2>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Type</th>
    <th></th><th></th></tr>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
        echo "<tr>";    
        //Output FirstName and LastName
        echo "<td>" .$row["MName"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row["Name"]."</td>";
```

I'm just not sure how to go about changing my Insert query such that it will accept the MonsterType.Name in the text field and use the MonsterType.ID associated with that MonsterType.Name in my Insert into Monsters table query.

Of course, ideally I'd just want my Monster Type field to be a dropdown list of all the MonsterType.Names but I was having issues doing a dropdown field using [HTML code embedded in a PHP block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynjjJ.png).

```
 echo '
    <div class="row">
    <label for="left-label" class="left inline">

    <h2>Add a monster</h2>
    <form method="POST" action="addMonsters.php">

    <p> Monster Name: <input type="text" name="Name">
    <p> Hit Points: <input type="text" name="HP">
    <p> Mana Points: <input type="text" name="MP">
    <p> Armor Class: <input type="text" name="AC">
    <p> Monster Type: <input type="text" name="MonsterType_ID">
    /////// This didn't work
    <p>Monster Type: <select name="Name">
    <option></option>
    <?php
         $query = "SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM MonsterType";
         $result = $mysqli->query($query);
         if($result && $result->num_rows>=1){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
               echo "<option value = '".$row['Name']."'>".$row['Name']."/option>";
        }
    }
         else {echo "<h2>No query results</h2>";}
     ?>
     </select>
      ///////////   
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button tiny round" value="Add monster" />
    </form>
    ';
```

If someone could solve this, that would be better.

Any guidance would be appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT:

I've successfully populated my dropdown using this block of code:

```
echo '<p>Monster Type: <select name="MonsterType_ID">';
        echo '<option></option>';

                $query = "SELECT DISTINCT ID, Name FROM MonsterType";
                $result = $mysqli ->query($query);
                if($result && $result->num_rows>=1){
                    while($row2 = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        if($row2['mID'] == $MonsterID){
                            echo "<option selected value = '".$row2['ID']."'>".$row2['Name']."</option>";
                        }
                        else{
                            echo "<option value = '".$row2['ID']."'>".$row2['Name']."</option>";
                        }
                    }
                }

                else {
                    echo "<h2>No query results</h2>";
                }
        echo '</select></p>';
```

However, this doesn't correctly POST to the original query, and I get the error message that I haven't filled in all the information. (I was missing a quotation marks around (select name="MonsterType_ID")) However, I'm still getting "Error! Could not add ".$_POST["Name"]."!"; So this means the result of the Query is false. Not sure what could be going on, except maybe MonsterType.ID is not getting matched to Monsters.MonsterType_ID.

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if( (isset($_POST["Name"]) && $_POST["Name"] !== "") && 
    (isset($_POST["HP"]) && $_POST["HP"] !== "") &&
    (isset($_POST["MP"]) && $_POST["MP"] !== "") &&
    (isset($_POST["AC"]) && $_POST["AC"] !== "") &&
    (isset($_POST["MonsterType_ID"]) && $_POST["MonsterType_ID"] !== "")     ) {



            //STEP 2.
                //Create query to insert information that has been posted
            $query = "INSERT INTO Monsters ";
            $query .= "(Name, HP, MP, AC, MonsterType_ID) ";
            $query .= "VALUES (";
            $query .= "'".$_POST["Name"]."',";
            $query .= "'".$_POST["HP"]."',";
            $query .= "'".$_POST["MP"]."',";
            $query .= "'".$_POST["AC"]."',";
            $query .= "'".$_POST["MonsterType_ID"]."'));";
            //$query .= "(SELECT ID FROM MonsterType WHERE Name='".$_POST["MonsterType_ID"]."'));";


            $result = $mysqli->query($query);

            // Execute query




        if($result) {

        $_SESSION["message"] = $_POST["Name"]." has been added!";
            header("Location: readMonsters.php");
            exit;

        }
        else {

        $_SESSION["message"] = "Error! Could not add ".$_POST["Name"]."!";
            header("Location: addMonsters.php");
            exit;
        }
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Unable to add monster. Fill in all information!";
        header("Location: addMonsters.php");
        exit;
    }
```

EDIT 2: Got everything working! The dropdown was correct, I just need to change the query to accept the proper parameter.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Monsters ";
            $query .= "(Name, HP, MP, AC, MonsterType_ID) ";
            $query .= "VALUES (";
            $query .= "'".$_POST["Name"]."',";
            $query .= "'".$_POST["HP"]."',";
            $query .= "'".$_POST["MP"]."',";
            $query .= "'".$_POST["AC"]."',";
            //$query .= "'".$_POST["MonsterType_ID"]."'));";
            $query .= "(SELECT ID FROM MonsterType WHERE ID='".$_POST["MonsterType_ID"]."'));";


            $result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Namely, I changed (SELECT ID FROM MonsterType WHERE Name=...) to (SELECT ID FROM MonsterType WHERE ID=...). My dropdown now successfully works. Thank you Nick for your help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), showcasing the code **itself**, rather than an image containing it. Being able to copy the code helps us debug it much faster. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Hi Connor, I've updated my answer - I didn't have time to write the complete thing earlier - and I think it has some more information you could find useful.

Comment: Hey Nick, I ended up doing something similar to what you provided, and I can successfully populate the dropdown field but it won't actually pass the MonsterType.ID to my query asking for Monsters.MonsterType_ID. Basically $_POST['MonsterType_ID'] in the query doesn't receive the ID from my dropdown, which is similar to the code you wrote.

Comment: I got everything working! I edited the main post to show my changes. Thank you Nick!

Comment: Great to hear. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, given your current code structure, change this line:

```
$query .= "'".$_POST["MonsterType_ID"]."');";
```

to

```
$query .= "(SELECT ID FROM MonsterType WHERE Name='".$_POST["MonsterType_ID"]."'));";
```

This will do a subquery select to get the appropriate ID from MonsterType for the name submitted.

Long Answer

The issue with this approach is that if a user types something into the MonsterType_ID text box that is not a valid MonsterType e.g. they mistype "Aberration" for "Abberation" this query will fail. Your attempt at generating a drop-down list is the right way to go. You will want something like this:

```
<p>Monster Type: <select name="MonsterType_ID">
<?php
     $query = "SELECT ID, Name FROM MonsterType";
     $result = $mysqli->query($query);
     if ($result) { 
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo "<option value = \"" . $row['ID'] . "\">" . $row['Name'] . "</option>";
        }
     }
 ?>
 </select>
```

This will give you a select where the option values (which are what gets passed to PHP in `$_POST`) are the ID's that you need to insert into the Monsters database. This way you don't need to do any pre-processing as described in the short answer (basically your existing code will work as is).

Comment: This did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a select when you do the insert.

```
INSERT INTO monsters (your, variable, fields, here, monsterTypeID) 
Select 'varname', 'varname', 'varname', 'varname', monsterTypeID FROM
MonsterTypeNames WHERE name='namevar';
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to query the monstertype table to get the id based on the monstertype name, and use the retrieved monstertype id to form part of your insert query.

So the solutions are that you either split it into two queries or use insert select(insert with subquery). If you split it into two queries, you will have to select, then insert. If you want to do it in one query, you can use insert select